# Does anyone know if the Cisco 3725 supports ADSL2

Tags: cisco

Does anyone know if the Cisco 3725 with a ADSL WIC supports ADSL2?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the WIC that supports ADSL2 is the HWIC-1ADSL which is the newer High-speed WAN Interface Cards which would not be supported in the 3700 series.  The WIC-1ADSL should be supported but does not support ADSL2 technology  If the provider's ADSL2 DSLAM supports ADSL clients , the WIC-1ADSL could work connected to an ADSL2 DSLAM just not at ADSL2 speeds.

Comment: Thanks for this that would explain why we are only getting 2Mbs on an ADSL2 DSLAM.